# oracle regular expression restrict position of character from right

Tags: regex, oracle

I am not able to proceed further and spent whole time to do google but didn't find a solution for my below query.

I want an Oracle regular expression that will meet the following requirements:

- starts with ABCD followed by variable length alphanumeric with 'N'
- present at 3nd or 4rd place from right.

E.g. `ABCD201312102751N11` or `ABCD201312102751N121`.

Comment: You mean 3rd or 4th from the right? `^ABCD[[:alnum:]]+N[[:digit:]]{2,3}$`?

Comment: @stribizhev yes yes  you are rockstar and I spent my half of day for it.Thanks a lot. I want to accept it as answer please update the answer.

Comment: I added the answer. And please post whatever you tried to the body of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you can use is:

```
^ABCD[[:alnum:]]+N[[:digit:]]{2,3}$
```

EXPLANATION:

- `^` - Start of string
- `ABCD` - Literal `ABCD`
- `[[:alnum:]]+` - Alphanumeric characters, 1 or more occurrences
- `N` - a literal `N`
- `[[:digit:]]{2,3}` - 2 or 3 digits (no more, no less)
- `$` - End of string.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vK6mB6/1)

Comment: BTW, the regex101.com understand the POSIX regex, but it can allow more. Be careful when testing your regexps there. I am using this only to show how the regex will work.